# Google+ not working with proxy server since last update

Tags: nexus-7, connection-issues, google-plus, proxy

Google+ on my device has stopped working since the last update. Every time, I get the message: `Can't load data. Check your connection`. All apps other than Google+ work absolutely fine.

My device details are as follows:
**Model:** Google Nexus 7 (2012)
**OS:** Android 4.4.2
**Google+ Build version:** 4.2.3.56698342

**Edit**: I use a Wifi on a proxy server for connection, and that's when the problem arises. When on a direct connection, the app works fine. But on proxy server, it has stopped working since the last update. Prior to this update, the app worked fine even on a proxy server.

Comment: Can you uninstall the update on G+? Then update it again via Google Play?

Comment: If you use the proxy, can you even open G+ on a browser?

Comment: @geffchang - Yes, I have already uninstalled and the re-installed the update via Google Play, but no improvement. Also yes, I can open G+ on the browser. As I said earlier, even the app used to work fine over proxy before its last update. Other apps such as YouTube, Facebook also work fine on proxy.

Comment: I was just wondering if G+ was blocked by the  proxy server. That's why I asked about checking it on the browser with proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Settings** --> **Apps** --> **Google+** -->Clear **Data & Cache**

It will solve most of the issues.

Comment: already tried that. no change in status.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, actually I've come here for the solution.

Clearing Data & Cache didn't help so I've decided to uninstall latest update. It worked for the original software so I gave a try and installed update once again. Now it works properly, so perhaps you could try to reinstall your update and see what happens?

Comment: tried it, but didn't help.

Comment: Does it work for you for the original software?

Comment: the app used to work fine prior to the last update.